# Edit custom properties cycles_visibility

Tags: rendering, properties, visibility

After boolean operation with BoolTool addon new line appeared in cycles_visibility under custom properties. After that, object is no longer visible on render. How to remove this line?[image: custom_properties]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to fix this. Just add new property, than ckick "Edit". In "Property name" type cycles_visibility and in "Property value" erase "1.0".